# initialization from incompatible pointer type - now what?

Tags: c++, eclipse, avr

I'm working in Eclipse Keppler with AVR plugin programming in C++.

The following is the issue:
The pointer to the array *midiPrioMemList creates an error.
Is it because midiPrioMemlist points to an uint8_t? What should it be then, an uint16_t does not quite solve the issue... any help or explanation is welcome :-)
The error shown is "initialization from incompatible pointer type"

```
uint8_t midiPrioMem0[priorityMemSize] = "1234567890";
uint8_t midiPrioMem1[priorityMemSize] = "qwertyuiop";
uint8_t midiPrioMem2[priorityMemSize] = "abcdefghij";

uint8_t *midiPrioMemList[] = {&midiPrioMem0, &midiPrioMem1, &midiPrioMem2};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&midiPrioMem0` degrades into a `uint8_t**`. `midiPrioMem0` is an array of `uint8_t`, which will degrade into a `uint8_t*`. Simply remove the `&`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue indeed.